# Separate chars in a spannable

Tags: android, spannable

I have a spannable, say `[12]`. I would like to read the numbers from between the `[` and the `]`. How can I do that for spannables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Spannable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html) is also a `CharSequence`. This means you can invoke `toString()`.

```
String s = mySpannable.toString();
```

Then you can match for whichever chars you want either with a regex, looping, or if you know that the characters you want are always enclosed between the square brackets and the brackets are always at the beginning and end, call `subString()` and exclude the positions of the brackets.

Keep in mind that `CharSequence` also has a [`charAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html#charAt%28int%29) method, so `toString()` may not even be needed.

Edit: If your digits are always enclosed in brackets, you can do this:

```
String withBrackets = "[1234567]";

String nums = s.substring (withBrackets.indexOf ("[")+1,withBrackets.indexOf ("]"));
System.out.println (nums);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how should I use `subString()` when I dont know if I have a one digit number or a two digit number? What should be the best approach in this case?

Comment: @BurninatorDor The simple method (assuming that the digits are always enclosed in the brackets, is using `indexOf()` to find each bracket).

Comment: Thank you so much! You ALWAYS give the best answers!